# I can't change the product image size for woocommerce

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, product, woothemes

I am trying to change the image size in the individual product page to be 600px X 700px however any changes from woocommerce product settings don't do anything even after I regenerate all thumbnails.  I think that something in my theme css is setting my product page image size but I can't figure out what it is so I can change it.

Also it would be a plus if I can remove the image border.  Here is a link to a product to see the issue I'm having.

http://goo.gl/OpLkMA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SOLVED]  It was in the theme file, each theme is different so posting the file name that I found mine in is likely irrelevant to anyone having this issue.

What you must do is look through your theme to see what size it renders thumbnails.  In my case, the largest width size of thumbnails was 360px.  Once I found the code below I simply changed it to 600px and then regenerated my thumbnails. That did the trick, I hope it helps someone with the same issue.

` /* ====== Product single thumb size ====== */

```
add_image_size( 'tw_shop_single', 360, 999, false );`
```

Answer (score 0):

A complete description of how to match Woocommerce thumbnail sizes with your theme is on our blog at http://www.cbdweb.net/woocommerce-and-image-sizes/
including links to the relevant Woocommerce documentation.   This question relates to how to change the size that images are displayed and the solution found is correct, but you still need to make sure the images stored by Woocommerce are resized to correctly match your (modified) theme.

It's also worth creating a child theme rather than modifying the theme directly. See documentation at http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Answer (score 0):

This will help you!

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_image_size_thumbnail', function( $size ) {
    return array(
    'width' => 427,
    'height' => 427,
    'crop' => 0,
    );
    } );
```

Comment: An explanation as to why this would help would be nice for people who find this in the future.