# Run a specific filter or function on WooCommerce checkout page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

actully i want to resize the cart item thumbnail on checkout page of WooCommerce currently i am using [I can't change the product image size for woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58613153/11987538) anser code in my child theme

but when i add this in my child functions .. it also resize the thubnail of main home page. i want this function to run only on woocommerce checkout page. please help me to fix that. i have tried is_page function also but running into error.

Comment: try to add item in cart and go to checkout on this website https://www.divyajadibuti.in/ currently i am using a function which works both home page and checkout but i want to run it on checkout page only you can cleary see at checkout page there is 2 images showing of same item the 2nd is bit bigger than 1st image .

Answer (score 0):

You can use Woocommerce Conditional tag of Checkout Page.

```
if ( is_checkout() ) {
  // Your Code Here
}
```

Source: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/

Comment: not working. no error but not happening.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the WooCommerce Visual Hook to run the code only on the checkout

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_checkout_form','function_name');
function function_name(){
   //your code here
}
```

source:https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-checkout-page

Comment: not working. no error but not happening.

Comment: Try echo something there to see if the code works in the check out page

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
if(is_checkout()){
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_image_size_thumbnail', function( $size ) {
        return array(
        'width' => 427,
        'height' => 427,
        'crop' => 0,
        );
    });
}
```